# Create react app breaks after deployment on refresh 404 with Nginx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, ibm-cloud, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app, it works fine on my local, with no issues at all. When I have it deployed on IBM Cloud, after login, when I refresh the page it gives **404 not found error** It was working fine earlier, not sure what happened.

I saw many related ques, The things I tried to solve and didn't work are following

**1.** **Created a static.json**

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

**2. I have this setup**

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true
  },
```

**3. I tried adding  around my Routers, didn't work**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
                <Route path="/some" component={Some} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
            </>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

**4. I tried to add the following**

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<HashRouter>
  <App/>
</HashRouter>
```

None of these seem to work for me. Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

When serving the `build/` output as a static site, you have to configure your nginx to always serve `index.html` (otherwise, it will attempt to match the url path to a static folder/file, which doesn't exist). More info on this behavior can be found in the `create-react-app` [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

If you're using the nginx docker image to serve your site, you need to set the following `default.conf`:

```
server {
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/$ {
        rewrite  ^.*$  /index.html  last;
    }
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Note the `rewrite  ^.*$  /index.html` part that modifies any incoming call and serves `index.html`.

Your minimal `Dockerfile` would then look like this:

```
FROM nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe that work this:

```
<HashRouter> 
  <Router>
    <Switch>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</HashRouter>
```

I think that you need build the application, and run this. I see an common error:

```
react-scripts start
/bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

I hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Thanks, Sebastián Sethson for your answer, which lead to the right path.

I updated my routing to

```
<HashRouter basename="/"> 
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
      <Route path="/some" component={Some} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```